# What are the Basic different between MEF for framework 3.5 and MEFfor framework 4.0?

Tags: mef

I try to below link for window application with MEF

http://geekswithblogs.net/malisancube/archive/2009/05/26/managed-extensibility-framework-101---a.aspx

it's work good in Framework 3.5 but when i try to develop same code for framework 4.0
not able to find below function

```
return container.GetExportedObject<Form1>();
```

please give me some properly example for window application with MEF where my container all the Usercontrols on Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MEF was being developed pre-.NET 4.0 but it became an official part of the framework from .NET 4.0 forwards.  The API you are looking for is actually the `ExportProvider.GetExportedValue<T>` method which `CompositionContainer` inherits from:

```
return container.GetExportedValue<Form1>();
```

`GetExportedObject` was renamed `GetExportedValue`, and it occurred with MEF preview 6, which means that blog post was actually based on quite an early revision of MEF.

Comment: this is not working in windows application. it's get the null value